# How to run a senario 1000 time using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

Scenario: Create 500/1000 Chat for a module Collaboration.

For Creating 50 Chat it is taking 5 mins now, I want to create 500 chat in minimum time, I used multithreading concept in protractor because this is an angular Application. And i as of now I m not able to create more than 40 chats.

Problem: Maximum is it allowing 5 browsers at a time.
and the major issue is for even 2 browsers are not working well. it is losing the focus in a browser.

Any suggestion in protractor or any other way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

> Please note that selenium is best used for web browser automation and
> is not design to create large amounts of data and/or to perform same
> steps simultaneously.

So if you wanted to create data in a minimum amount of time. The best way to do this is to use Performance Testing Software like [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi), HP LoadRunner. That way, you can utilize a large number of users performing these steps to be able to create your data. And the limit of the number of threads is dependent on your load generator - machine's specifications.